# Are signing bonuses common place in Australia?

Tags: salary, negotiation, bonus, australia

Signing bonuses: are they utilised by Australian companies regularly enough, that to ask for one when negotiating salary for a new job, would be considered 'ok'?

Comment: This is probably industry dependent.

Comment: In 17 years of IT work in Australia, I've never received one, never offered one to a candidate when making a job offer, and never heard anyone ever speak of having gotten or offered one. Make of that what you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard of it occurring, but certainly not commonplace.

The cases where I've heard it occurring are to offset a bonus. For example, if someone is due X as a bonus the hiring company may match this.